# GETDATE( ) in columns in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a way to create a table in which the `DATE` column updated every date with the current date?

I want a column that every time I `select` gives me the current date.

`GETDATE()` function gives the current date but I don't manage to use it in order to get the current date every day.

The primary objective was to create a table, but I think it might be better to use a view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create a computed column, as described here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-ver15

Just because you can, doesn't mean you should, though.

A better way to do it would be to create a view like this:

```
    create view example_view
    as
    select *, getdate() as today
    from my_table
```

Then call the view:

```
    select * from example_view
```

Answer (score 3):

Include the date function as part of your query:

```
SELECT ColA, ColB, GETDATE() AS [Date]
FROM dbo.Table;
```